# BroadcastReceiver not triggered for SMS_RECEIVED on Galaxy S II

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have the latest update for my Samsung Galaxy S2 and now my application stop working (App don't receive sms). I have SMSReceiver extends from BroadcastReceiver with SMS_RECEIVED action.

It looks like this:

```
private class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context cntxt, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "New broadcast receiver");
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(TAG, 0);
            if (settings.getString("authCode", "").equals("")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Get sms");
                if (intent.getAction().toString().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        }
                        if (messages.length > -1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Read sms");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I register BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
mSmsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
filter.setPriority(100000);
registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, filter);
```

Everything works on HTC Desire or Desire Z and android emulator. On Galaxy S2 my SMSReceiver don't receive any Intent when SMS came. I tried all solution but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried to mov your BR registration from java code to xml declaration? AFIK galaxy has it's own UI extension which can produce problems like that.

Comment: I assume you're not seeing the line 'New broadcast receiver' in your logs?

Comment: That's right David. I spend 4 hours on this and I dont't have any idea whats is wrong. That's funny, because one week ago, everything worked ok.

Comment: I found out why I have problem with BroadcastReceiver. Go SMS Pro was updated and it wont to set settings. Probably it blocked something.

Comment: From the logs, it seems that there's an app called Mobile Tracker which blocks other SMS receivers. Gah!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a issue with the [latest version of GoSMS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uRQsgHFdiTo)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with the "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" action on the Galaxy s2. Couldn't receive reconnection intent when the Broadcast receiver was registered in the code. 
Registering the broadcast receiver in the manifest was the solution for me.